# filtering scores from one variable and placing them in a new variable

Tags: r, dataframe

##So I have this variable test scores is coded on a scale from 1-9.
I have to take those who score 1-3 as low, 4-6 as good and 7-9 as high in new variables.
then have to make a new variable that compares low and high and a variable that compares low and good.

```
test_scores<- c(sample(1:10, 122, replace = TRUE)

test_scores<-as.data.frame(test_scores)
low<- filter(test_scores,test_scores1 > 3)
high<- filter(test_scores, test_scores< 7)
good<-filter(test_scores,test_scores== 4:6)
```

##but the N of in the new variables are not counting up to 122

##I thought of using the if function:

```
low<- ifelse(test_scores$test_scores == 1:3 , 1:3 , 0)
mods<- ifelse(test_scores$test_scores == 4:6, 4:6, 0) 
high<- ifelse(test_scores$test_scores == 7:9, 7:9, 0)
```

##but some scores are not getting filter instead they become 0 even tho the score matches. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "cut" to generate the new bins:

```r
set.seed(123)
test_scores <- sample(1:9, 122, T)
test_scores
#>   [1] 3 3 2 6 5 4 6 9 5 3 9 9 9 3 8 7 9 3 4 1 7 5 7 9 9 7 5 7 5 6 9 2 5 8 2 1 9
#>  [38] 9 6 5 9 4 6 8 6 6 7 1 6 2 1 2 4 5 6 3 9 4 6 9 9 7 3 8 9 3 7 3 7 6 5 5 8 3
#>  [75] 2 2 6 4 1 6 3 8 3 8 1 7 7 7 6 7 5 6 8 5 7 4 3 9 7 6 9 7 2 3 8 4 7 4 1 8 4
#> [112] 9 8 6 4 8 3 4 4 6 1 4

cuts <- cut(test_scores, c(0,3,6,9), labels = F)
cuts
#>   [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 2 1 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 1 2 1 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 1 2 3 1 1 3
#>  [38] 3 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 3 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 3 2 2 3 3 3 1 3 3 1 3 1 3 2 2 2 3 1
#>  [75] 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 3 2 1 3 3 2 3 3 1 1 3 2 3 2 1 3 2
#> [112] 3 3 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 1 2
```

if you want a variable for each bin, and zero otherwise, you must use `%in%`, not `==`

```
low<- ifelse(test_scores$test_scores %in% 1:3 , test_scores$test_scores , 0)
mods<- ifelse(test_scores$test_scores %in% 4:6, test_scores$test_scores, 0) 
high<- ifelse(test_scores$test_scores %in% 7:9, test_scores$test_scores, 0)
```